# Word shortcut to start bulleted list

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, bullets

I know there exists a keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to create a new bullet point, but this does not add the appropriate indentation.  Is there a keyboard shortcut that exists or that I can define to emulate the behavior of clicking on the bulleted list button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For bulleted lists, type `*` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

You can start other styles of lists with similar shortcuts.

For numbered lists, type `1.`, `1)` or `(1)` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

You can also use `a` or `A` for lowercase or uppercase lettered lists, with your choice of brackets or period.

For Roman numeral lists, use `i` or `I`.

Comment: That's right, this functionality does exist.  Out of curiosity though, would you know of a menu/ribbon function that I can map a keyboard shortcut to?

Comment: On Windows, press `Alt + H` to see all the shortcuts for the Home ribbon. You can then press `U` for the bulleted list dropdown or `N` for the number dropdown.

Comment: Also true.  Now I just need a way to remember things I already know when I need them.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a keyboard shortcut that exists or that I can define to emulate the behavior of clicking on the bulleted list button?

To answer this part of your question: there is a way of *precisely* doing this, i.e. **assigning a keyboard shortcut to any button on any ribbon in the MS-Word**. Here's what you do:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad Plus</kbd> keys together to enter the mode where you can assign a keyboard shortcut. You should see the "looped square knot" (`⌘`) symbol in place of the cursor arrow.
2. Now, you just have to point to and click the button to which you want to assign a shortcut and
3. you will be shown a window where you could assign the shortcut.

Alternately look into this [blog post](http://mswordtipsandtricks.blogspot.co.at/2017/01/easiest-way-to-customize-keyboard.html), or to this video on YouTube: [Easiest way of assigning keyboard shortcuts in MS-Word](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hL2peuNAdrA).